# Fitting a background image to a div

Tags: css

I'm using the following css to make a div always full size on screen,

```
.container{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background: url("../assets/shutterstock_585038551.jpg");
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
```

However only and part of the background image shows up, How do I fit the background image without changing it's aspect ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS.

```
background-size: cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

This assumes that your `.container` div is full width and height.

If it isn't, also add the following:

```
width: 100vw;
height:100vh;
```

Some information on background size.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Some information on `vh` and `vw`

https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

Comment: keep only the MDN link, please remove the w3school one

Comment: @TemaniAfif Whilst for JS I wouldn't post W3, but for basic CSS, W3 isn't incorrect so I think its ok to stay.

Comment: w3 isn't correct for this particular case, but if you tell someone to go there for background-size he will for sure use it for other properties and other things (JS also) since he will find them there. So you aren't simply linking to one page but to the whole site.